# Trying to understand PDO in PHP; keep getting null error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to figure out why my PDO methods keep returning null values. Everything seems correct, from the prepare to the execute.

> i.e. "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in
>   /blah/register.php on line 5"

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if ($email === ''){
    unset($email);
}else{
    $query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT email FROM `Members` WHERE email=:input_email');
    $query->execute(array(':input_email' => $email));
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        echo $row['email'] . "<br />";
    }
var_dump($query);
die();
}
```

This code should echo all values, and then kill the rest of the script.

db connect:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'dbuser', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                                                                                                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "<b>Sorry, this website is experiencing problems. </b>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You are mixing mysqli and pdo!! post your database connection code too

Comment: And with this query `SELECT email FROM `Members` WHERE email=:input_email` you always get `$email`

Comment: oh wow just realized its using mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing mysqli and pdo in your code you need to change `mysqli prepare with`pdo prepare`

```
 $query = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM `Members` WHERE email=:input_email');
          ^^^ //add pdo object here
```

You need to add fetch data form your execute statement

```
 $query = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM `Members` WHERE email=:input_email');
 $query->execute(array(':input_email' => $email));
 $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 print_r($result);
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out.